# understanding php start & close tags

Tags: php

```
<?php
function outLala() {
?>
  lala
<?php   
}
?>
```

the result of this php file is a blank page instead of a page with text "lala".

if i change the code as

```
<?php
function outLala() {}
?>
  lala
<?php   
{}
?>
```

the result of this php file is a page with text "lala".

does it mean that the php interpreter will parse the code inside the open and the close tag, and if it finds a function(or something else) is not properly terminated,  the interpreter will think the content following the close tag is part of the function?

Comment: Well... `lala` is inside the `outLala()` function definition, so... I guess it gets output whenever the function is called, but I've never seen anyone write PHP code like that.

Comment: Wordpress themes are not generally to be considered PHP best practice.

Answer (score 3):

This is valid PHP, but you don't call the function. Add

```
outLala();
```

at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You must call function outLala. Example:

```
<?php
function outLala() {
?>
  lala
<?php   
}
outLala();
?>
```